# Thirdparty library certificate is not added to apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I use thirdparty library which require their certificate file to work. The certificate is bound to app package and its file should be placed in the package with special name. Here what I mean:

MyApp:

```
src
|-main
  |-java
    |-com.library.package
       |-library.certificate
    |-my.app.package
```

Moreover, the library is added as a library project and the library package name exactly the same as package where I should place certificate (com.library.package). All code of the library is packed in *.jar file.

So in my build script I have the next code:

> dependencies {
>
> compile project(':lib')
>
> compile files('../lib/libs/lib.jar')
>
> }

But as a result the library file is not added to the apk. The library code is successfully added to the apk.
This project and code is working on Eclipse (the certificate is added to the apk).

I assume that Gradle build library and add all packages from the library to the app, but then ignore the certificate package and skip adding.
What can I do?

Comment: Can you put it in your assets folder instead?

Comment: I can't because the library will not be certificated.  It is requirement to put it into this package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding next code to gradle script:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
}
```